# Express enable client side caching

Tags: node.js, express, caching, browser-cache

I am trying to cache a file client side with NodeJs and Express.

Here an example of what I am trying to do :

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req:any, res:any)=>  res.send('Hello World!') );
app.get('/file', (req:any, res:any)=> {
    console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=60'); 
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname+'/../file.pdf'));
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!') );
```

Then I browse the file twice and I expect to have only one log `Request URL: /file`. But with this code I got two. It seems that either my `Cache-Control` headers is ignored by the browser or it get mixed up with default Express behavior like `ETag`..

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but first thing that I thought about was the file size.
Maybe it is too big?

[what-is-chrome-default-cache-size-limit](https://superuser.com/questions/378991/what-is-chrome-default-cache-size-limit)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, if you are not sure if this would solve the problem, and cant verify by testing it, then maybe consider posting this as a comment on the question instead of as an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31538883)